# Including sql server compact in desktop install for win 7 32bit and 64bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce, sql-server-ce

I have a desktop app created in vs10 and am using clickonce install. I must include a database with critical info for the program as part of the install.  I am compiling for all versions of windows (32 and 64).  But as I understand it, if I include the 32 bit sqlce as part of the installation, it will not work on 64 bit installs.  Must I include a 32 bit and 64 bit version of the db and test for windows version before accessing the data?  Or is there a simpler solution that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can just include all the required files as content with your app, and it will run for any user and on both x86 and x64 platforms. Just follow the instructions here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: So, even if I create a 32 bit db containing my data on my development computer and include it in the install, people with a win 64 bit os will be able to access that db as long as I include both 86x and 64x files?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The dtabase file itself does not have any "bitness"